# Choosing the right model for prediction

Tags: time-series, regression

Given a set of temperatures of different cities for a month, which prediction model should I use for a two day look ahead prediction? Regression models or Time series?

Comment: It seems to me, that a regression model for time series is in order. How do you think that regression and time series are mutually excluding?

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of an absolute or *a priori* answer, you could use your existing temperature data to evaluate the performance of the different prediction methods.

E.g. say you have 30 days of temperature data. Perform a set of trials, for both models, where you train the model on some initial segment of the data, say, days `1..n`, where `n<28`, and record the prediction of the model for day `n+2`. This will give you some empirical evidence of the performance of the different models, given *your* data.

If you need more temperature data, you could always use a massive dataset like [Berkeley Earth](http://berkeleyearth.org/about-data-set).